# Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Y'

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, typescript

I have created those types:

```
export type Optional<T> = T | null;
```

and I have this function

```
updateBook( book: Array<Optional<Hostel>>)
```

that I call with

```
 let book: Hostel | null [] = [null];
 updateBook(book)
```

but I have this error

```
 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Hostel | null[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Optional<Hostel>[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hostel | null []` means a union between `Hostel` and `null[]`. The `[]` has a higher precedence than the union operator (`|`).

You probably wanted to say an array of `Hostel | null` which can be written as `(Hostel | null)[]` or, more readably IMO `Array<Hostel | null>`.